gitlab pages: user.gitlab.io being served at user.gitlab.io/user.gitlab.io
As per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#user-and-group-website-examples:

Under your username, john, you created a project called john.gitlab.io. Your project URL is https://gitlab.com/john/john.gitlab.io. After you enabled GitLab Pages for your project, your website is published under https://john.gitlab.io

This used to work fine for me. However, recently I saw that my personal website is no longer being deployed to matheustavares.gitab.io, but to matheustavares.gitlab.io/matheustavares.gitlab.io
Any ideas why or how to fix this?
I've tried renaming the project, checking visibility settings, enabling and disabling the "unique domain" feature, all with no success.
